# I calculated the current using mesh analysis but got two contradicting results. Which is right?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

Mesh analysis on loop 1
$$
10i_{0}+40i_{0}+5v_{0}=0\\
50i_{0}=-5v_{0} \Rightarrow i_{0}=-0.1v_{0}\\
$$
By the way, since the current source and the resistor on the leftmost are in parallel

$$
v_{0}=i_{s}\times30=30i_{s}\\
\Rightarrow i_{0}=-0.1\times30i_{s}=-3i_{s}
$$

But if I use VCL on the node $$v_{0}$$ then I get

$$
i_{s}=\frac{V_{0}}{30}+\frac{v_{0}+5v_{0}}{20}=\frac{v_{0}}{3}\\
\Rightarrow v_{0}=3i_{s}\\
\Rightarrow i_{0}=-0.1\times3i_{s}=-0.3i_{s}
$$

I get two different results.
I guess using the VCL on the node v0 is wrong since 5v0 is a dependent source.
Am I right?
What is the point that I'm missing here?

Comment: Try to use KCL and find out by yourself.

Comment: Or, use a simulation tool to give you the correct answer.

Comment: @Andyaka Can't simulate it since if **V0** is zero volts that's a solution. In fact, any value for **V0** is a solution as **IS** also isn't specified.

Answer (score 7):

You have mistakenly assumed that all of the current from the current source goes through the 30 ohm resistor. Don't you think that the current will split between that resistor and the path through the 20 ohm resistor?

Answer (score 3):

You are allowed to assign one node as ground. I've chosen your bottom wire for that. Here's your circuit, redrawn:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fN2BPT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(You should use the built-in schematic editor, by the way. It numbers the parts for you.)

That makes it very easy to write down the equations. But it won't produce any quantitative values, as setting \$V_0=0\:\text{V}\$ works fine if \$I_{_\text{S}}=0\:\text{A}\$. In fact, you can use any value for either \$V_0\$ or \$I_{_\text{S}}\$ (but not both, obviously) and compute the other one from that.

All this circuit does is set up a relationship between the two values. There is no specific quantitative answer for both values. You need more information, if that's the goal.